# Save NetCDF through Xarray with dimensions given by two coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, geopandas, python-xarray

I have geographical information in a geopandas. I have a function that saves that information to a netcdf through `xarray` as follows

```
def write_ncfile(name, new_model, variables):
    ## Distinct latitudes
    lats=new_model.drop_duplicates(["ilat"], keep="first").geometry.y.values
    ## Distinct Longitudes
    lons=new_model.drop_duplicates(["ilon"], keep="first").geometry.x.values

    ## Temporal store for DataArrays
    temporal_dataset = {}

    ## Dimensions and coordinates
    dims = ('lat', 'lon')
    coords = dict(lat=lats, lon=lons)

    ## Variables to save
    for variable in variables:
        bcvar=new_model[variable].values
        ## Reshapes data to have sahpe of lats and lons
        bcvar=np.reshape(bcvar, (-1, len(lons)))
        ds = xr.DataArray(bcvar, dims=dims, coords=coords)
        ds.attrs['long_name'] = descriptions[variable] 
        ds.attrs['_FillValue'] = 0
        temporal_dataset[variable] = ds
    ## Create DataSet
    DT=xr.Dataset(temporal_dataset)

    ## Save to file
    makedirs(name, exist_ok = True)
    filename="%s/%s.nc"%(name, name)
    DT.to_netcdf(filename, format="NETCDF4_CLASSIC")

    return None
```

This code works wonderfully if the underlaying geographical grid is squared (lat lon projection) but now if the projection is not square (ex lambert) then I would need to have the dimensions defined as a 2d array not 1d. I am stumped as to how to do that.

I am trying to achieve something like this in the header of `ncdump`

```
dimensions:
lat:dim_lat
lon:dim_lon
variables:
double lat(lat, lon)
double lon(lat, lon)
double var1(lat, lon)
double var2(lat, lon)
```

Currently the code is saving it as

```
dimensions:
lat:dim_lat
lon:dim_lon
variables:
double lat(lat)
double lon(lon)
double var1(lat, lon)
double var2(lat, lon)
```

How can I change this?

---

Example gdf:

```
     ilat  ilon                   geometry            d_p         T_P          d_v         T_V              
22     0     0  POINT (-70.95000 -33.30000)      0.000000           0     0.000000           0              
0      0     1  POINT (-70.85000 -33.30000)    383.862700       39674   120.439438       12448              
1      0     2  POINT (-70.75000 -33.30000)    327.639330       33863   112.502638       11628              
2      0     3  POINT (-70.65000 -33.30000)    320.808104       33157    96.602750        9984              
3      0     4  POINT (-70.55000 -33.30000)    415.217240       42915    99.144774       10247              
23     1     0  POINT (-70.95000 -33.40000)      0.000000           0     0.000000           0              
4      1     1  POINT (-70.85000 -33.40000)     56.055971        5787    16.853605       17310              
5      1     2  POINT (-70.75000 -33.40000)   6686.807845      690341  1992.373592      205691            
6      1     3  POINT (-70.65000 -33.40000)   8812.040534      909749  3512.456618      362623              
7      1     4  POINT (-70.55000 -33.40000)   5203.112762      537166  2015.376536      208066              
24     2     0  POINT (-70.95000 -33.50000)      0.000000           0     0.000000           0              
8      2     1  POINT (-70.85000 -33.50000)    133.485233       13765    40.937021        4222              
9      2     2  POINT (-70.75000 -33.50000)   7358.668562      758846  2309.069300      238118              
10     2     3  POINT (-70.65000 -33.50000)  10420.377036     1074578  3668.947758      378352              
11     2     4  POINT (-70.55000 -33.50000)   6166.780423      635935  2047.500621      211144              
12     3     0  POINT (-70.95000 -33.60000)     71.933395       74010    21.287101        2193              
13     3     1  POINT (-70.85000 -33.60000)   1154.803477      118952   373.474444       38470              
14     3     2  POINT (-70.75000 -33.60000)   1512.189352      155764   466.310819       48033              
15     3     3  POINT (-70.65000 -33.60000)   7160.093545      737532  2095.296251      215828              
16     3     4  POINT (-70.55000 -33.60000)   4870.217943      501661  1494.220152      153914              
17     4     0  POINT (-70.95000 -33.70000)    767.033734       78919   241.884877       24887              
18     4     1  POINT (-70.85000 -33.70000)    163.023696       16773    48.526857        4993              
19     4     2  POINT (-70.75000 -33.70000)    632.011798       65027   207.326845       21332              
20     4     3  POINT (-70.65000 -33.70000)     93.053338        9574    27.787137        2859
```

And the function usage would be

```
write_ncfile("Trial", gdf, ["d_p", "d_v"])
```

In the example above saves the information just fine with the code above, but I need to generalize it so that it works when the grid is not a square grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and xarray is not very intuitiv on that point. The solution to create a `DataArray` with the right dimension (Note this is a 3D example):

```
    data_array = xarray.DataArray(
        data,
        coords={
            "time": timestamps,
            "latitude": (["y", "x"], latitude_grid),
            "longitude": (["y", "x"], longitude_grid),
        },
        dims=["time", "y", "x"],
    )
```

So the loop in your code should look like this:

```
    coords = {
            "latitude": (["lon", "lat"], latitude_grid),
            "longitude": (["lon", "lat"], longitude_grid)}
    dims = ['lon', 'lat']
    for variable in variables:
        bcvar=new_model[variable].values
        ## Reshapes data to have sahpe of lats and lons
        bcvar=np.reshape(bcvar, (-1, len(lons)))
        ds = xr.DataArray(bcvar, dims=dims, coords=coords)
        ds.attrs['long_name'] = descriptions[variable] 
        ds.attrs['_FillValue'] = 0
        temporal_dataset[variable] = ds
```

Feel free to adapt this to your final running solution.